# why is visualforce page is not working when user create unmanagedpackage.and insatll it another dev org

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have create a visaulforce page.and a component.I have call this component on page.when i preview this page it is working fine.I follow this link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm

Than I have create a unmanaged package in my org.I have insatll this package in my new dev org.Here is my all components but its component tab not come with my package.but vf tab ishere.Now when i click my vftab  page is blank.and gives this error:

> `https://lightdroisys-dev-ed--c.ap2.visual.force.com/c/LightningTest.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT`

I didn't know why this error is here?and my is not working.Please help me where I am wrong and can we create our package only using component without to create visualforce pages?